(bootloader) command is not implemented!
I'm having a problem when trying to boot into a twrp. When I try to use the fastboot boot twrp.img it returns with the error

(bootloader) command is not implemented!

Sending 'boot.img' (33144 KB)
OKAY [  1.047s]
Booting                                            (bootloader) command is not implemented!
OKAY [  0.007s]
Finished. Total time: 1.093s

I'm using Ubuntu MATE 24.10, and it is my first root and I'm trying to do it on a Moto g8 Play.
(sorry if my english is bad)

If I am not mistaken your phone has a MediaTek SOC, and those phones are to my knowledge not flashed via fastboot as they don't implement full fastboot mode. Follow the model specific TWRP instructions to use TWRP.

Try
fastboot flash recovery twrp.img
It flashes TWRP to recovery partition instead of temporarily booting it, which isn't supported on most devices.

To improve your answer please explain what the parameters mean, or add a section of the help.
